# Get data from previous month (non consecutive)

Tags: sql

current table is looks like this, the months are not consecutive hence using `lag` function would not be accurate.

is there any way that I can match the yr and mth to retrieve the previous month data?

| category | yr | mnth | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | 2019 | 1 | 100 |
| Furniture | 2019 | 3 | 700 |
| Furniture | 2019 | 4 | 800 |
| Furniture | 2020 | 1 | 100 |
| Furniture | 2020 | 2 | 200 |
| Furniture | 2020 | 4 | 800 |

Comment: LAG retrieves the previous record in an ordered list. There's no requirement that the records are "consecutive"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not clarified what language you are using, I will answer with a more general term of logic.

If you want to retrieve data matching last month. You have to set up variables to today's date and make a small calculation.

```
if ($todays_month != 1){
    $last_month = $todays_month - 1;
}
else{
    $last_month = 12;
}
```